# Strip custom properties from a PDF using iTextSharp or iText

Tags: itext

Is it possible to strip custom properties from a PDF using iTextSharp? I can modify existing properties using the `PdfStamper.MoreInfo` property, but I don't see a simple way to remove them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm gonna guess that setting them to null will remove them...

Yep.  From the [JavaDoc for PdfStamper](http://api.itextpdf.com/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfStamper.html):

```
/** An optional <CODE>String</CODE> map to add or change values in
  * the info dictionary. Entries with <CODE>null</CODE>
  * values delete the key in the original info dictionary
  * @param moreInfo additional entries to the info dictionary
  *
  */
public void setMoreInfo(HashMap<String, String> moreInfo) {
    this.moreInfo = moreInfo;
}
```

You you'll get the existing moreInfo, set any keys you want to get rid of to null, and then `setMoreInfo()`.  No problem.

Translate that into C#-ese, and you're good to go.